# Are package animate and beamer still compatible?

Tags: beamer, animate

A minimal example below

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\frame{
  Hello, world.
}    
\end{document}
```

Gives me:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...g_pbs_bop_seq {##1}}\box_use_drop:N 
                                                  \@outputbox \hbox_overlap_...
l.7 }
```

Comment: That error suggests your `expl3` version doesn't match `animate`: what TeX system do you have?

Comment: update your TeX system and try a again

Comment: The example compiles without error for me. What versions of `beamer`, `animate` and `expl3` are you using? I have `beamer 2018/12/02 v3.55`, `animate.sty 2018/12/19` and `expl3.sty 2019-01-01`. You can find out your package versions easily if you add `\listfiles` to the start of your MWE file, the versions will then be listed in a convenient table in the `.log` file.

Comment: `animate` depends on `expl3` via `pdfbase.sty` contained in `media9`. A full package update of the TeX distribution should fix everything.

Comment: unrelated to your problem: instead of `\frame{...}` better use `\begin{frame}...\end{frame}`

Comment: Thanks everybody for suggesting an update, that was'nt obvious at all to me. I'lll try soon and keep you informed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved by update

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the stated problem is caused by old package versions. It can be solved by a package update.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, the TeX distribution was not up to date. Updating it solved the problem, sorry for polluting StackExchange with my silly question.

Comment: So, I think we can close this question. This is the standard procedure for problems that can be solved by package updates.

Comment: (Don't feel offended by the close reason in the box below the question. It was automatically generated.)

Comment: That's OK, my mistake